# Fullcalendar Rails- Event does not appear on the calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, fullcalendar

i have git clone fullcalendar_assets and it's running smoothly and event showing.

my application rails 3.2.6 using postgresql for dbms. I try to apply fullcalendar in my application. but event not appear.

to the point.

on routes.rb

```
namespace admin do
 resources :events
end
```

on admin/events_conttroler.rb

```
class Admin::EventsController < ApplicationController
  include Tenantable::Schema::Controller

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!

  def index
    @events = Event.scoped
    @events = Event.between(params['start'], params['end']) if (params['start'] && params['end'])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: ([:admin, @events]) }
    end
  end
```

on event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tenantable::Schema::Model

  scope :between, lambda {|start_time, end_time|
    {:conditions => [
  "starts_at > ? and starts_at < ?",
  Event.format_date(start_time), Event.format_date(end_time)
] }
  }

  # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
  # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :nama => self.nama,
      :keterangan=> self.keterangan || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.adminsekolah_event_path(id),
      #:color => "red"
    }

  end

  def self.format_date(date_time)
    Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
  end

end
```

and on events.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar
    editable: true,
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,

    eventSources: [{
      url: '/admin/events',
    }],

    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5"

    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);

    eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);


updateEvent = (the_event) ->
  $.update "/events/" + the_event.id,
    event:
      nama: the_event.nama,
      starts_at: "" + the_event.start,
      ends_at: "" + the_event.end,
      keterangan: the_event.keterangan
```

i try to add one event and event put on database (schema : subdomain / not public), it's smoothly but i run localhost:3000/admin/events , event does not appear on the calendar (not error)

following command such as

```
Started GET "/admin/events?start=1353776400&end=1357405200&_=135557072567
2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-15 18:25:25 +0700
Processing by Admin::EventsController#index as JSON
Parameters: {"start"=>"1353776400", "end"=>"1357405200", "_"=>"1355570725672"}
Admin Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "public"."admins".* FROM "public"."admins" WHERE "public"."admins"."id" = 25 LIMIT 1
Event Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at > '2012-11-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 3.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

i try the query in psql

```
education_development=# SELECT * FROM subdomain.events WHERE (starts_at > '2012-11-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
education_development-# ;
id |     name      |       starts_at        |        ends_at         | all_day|   description    |         created_at         |         updated_at
----+---------------+------------------------+------------------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
1 | New Year 2013 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00+07 | 2013-01-01 00:00:00+07 | f | New Year 2013 | 2012-12-15 06:53:50.695456 | 2012-12-15 06:53:50.695456
(1 row)
```

any idea for this issue?

Comment: I see that the request you mentioned is done as JSON, is it deliberate?

Comment: yes it is, Initially I did git clone from https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar_assets , it's running smoothly and event showing, problems appear when fullcalendar applied to my application as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is because the JSON returned from the controller, it should return an array of events but instead it returns an array of 'admin' as the first element and array of events as the second element, which fullcalendar doesn't expect. Simply use

```
      format.json { render json: @events }
```

and it should work.

**UPDATE**: Also you localized the hash keys of the JSON representation of your event object, you must use the the same keys in fullcalendar `model/event.rb`.

Comment: nothing changes, it seems the problem is located here 
`eventSources: [{ url: '/admin/events',  }],`
because `Admin::EventsController`

Comment: Would you please post the output the request from your browser console?

Comment: `Started GET "/admin/events?start=1353776400&end=1357405200&_=135558877394
9" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-15 23:26:13 +0700
Processing by Admins::EventsController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"start"=>"1353776400", "end"=>"1357405200", "_"=>"1355588773949"}
Admin Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "public"."admins".* FROM "public"."admins" WHERE "public"."admins"."id" = 25 LIMIT 1
  Event Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at > '2012-1
1-25 00:00:00' and starts_at < '2013-01-06 00:00:00')
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 7.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)`

Comment: No, I mean from Network tab in your Chrome Developer Tools or Firefox Firebug; the JSON returned I mean :).

Comment: hihi sorry..

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined fullcalendar.js:1845
htmlEscape fullcalendar.js:1845
daySegHTML fullcalendar.js:4662
renderDaySegs fullcalendar.js:4528
renderEvents fullcalendar.js:2618
rerenderEvents fullcalendar.js:527
reportEvents fullcalendar.js:512
(anonymous function) fullcalendar.js:926
_fetchEventSource.$.ajax.$.extend.success fullcalendar.js:988
fire jquery.js:975
self.fireWith jquery.js:1085
done jquery.js:7804
callback jquery.js:8519`

Comment: what do you mean "the same keys".

Comment: In `to_json` method in `app/models/event.rb`, you changed `:title` to `:nama`, `:description` to `:keterangan` and so on, you shouldn't make these changes/localizations, keep them as is.

Comment: that's great brother, thank you for your guidance.. one more , why I can not edit or resize,,?