# Fullcalendar Rails Dragable/Resize not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

My first problem has been solved [event not appear](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13893107/1699254)
but another problems arise, I cannot drag and resize.

on events.js.coffee :

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar
    editable: true,
    header:
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    defaultView: 'month',
    height: 500,
    slotMinutes: 30,

    eventSources: [{
      url: '/admin/events',
    }],

    timeFormat: 'h:mm t{ - h:mm t} ',
    dragOpacity: "0.5"

    eventDrop: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);

    eventResize: (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) ->
      updateEvent(event);


updateEvent = (the_event) ->
  $.update "/admin/events/" + the_event.id,
    event:
      name: the_event.title,
      starts_at: "" + the_event.start,
      ends_at: "" + the_event.end,
      ket: the_event.description
```

on browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' fullcalendar.js:2676
draggableDayEvent fullcalendar.js:2676
bindDaySeg fullcalendar.js:2658
(anonymous function) fullcalendar.js:1717
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3059
elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2677
```

assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require redactor-rails
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-alert
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require jquery.rest
//= require jquery.ui.slider
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require fullcalendar
```

Comment: Would you please post the content of your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?

Comment: `jquery-ui` already includes `jquery.ui.slider` and `jquery.ui.datepicker`, did you try to remove them (from filesystem and `application.js`) and see if it works?

Comment: there was no change

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable' fullcalendar.js:2676
draggableDayEvent fullcalendar.js:2676
bindDaySeg fullcalendar.js:2658
(anonymous function) fullcalendar.js:1717
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3059
elemData.handle.eventHandle jquery.js:2677`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved

change

```
//= require jquery.ui.slider
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
```

to

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Comment: Similar issue, I added jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js to resolve the issue